# Tweepy error Stream.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'access_token' and 'access_token_secret'

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to set up a Retweet bot using the Tweepy module for Twitter's API, and have been working through errors bit by bit as the tutorial I was following was an older version of Tweepy. I'm new-ish to Python coding, and certainly haven't integrated API's before, so bear with me on this :)

Here's my code:

```
# import dependencies
import tweepy
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from streamlistener import StreamListener

# load our .env file to make use of the environment variables
load_dotenv()

# import and assign our environment variables
API_KEY = os.getenv('twitter_api_key')
API_SECRET = os.getenv('twitter_api_secret')
ACCESS_TOKEN = os.getenv('twitter_access_token')
TOKEN_SECRET = os.getenv('twitter_access_secret')

# instantiate oauth handler and set access token
twitter_oauth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
twitter_oauth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, TOKEN_SECRET)

# instantiate tweepy api object using the authentication handler object
twitter_api = tweepy.API(twitter_oauth)

# attempt credential verification. prints exception if something is wrong
try:
    print(twitter_api.verify_credentials())
    print("Successfully logged in")
except tweepy.errors.TweepyException as e:
    print(e)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    
# instantiate a StreamListener object
tweets_listener = StreamListener(twitter_api)

#instantiate a tweepy.Stream object
tweet_stream = tweepy.Stream(twitter_api.auth, tweets_listener)

# Use the filter method
tweet_stream.filter(track=["#VTuber", "#ENVTuber", "vtuber", "Vtuber", "VTuberEN"], languages=["en"])
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python\bot.py", line 36, in <module>     tweet_stream = tweepy.Stream(twitter_api.auth, tweets_listener) TypeError: Stream.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'access_token' and 'access_token_secret'
```

I've tried adding ACCESS_TOKEN and TOKEN_SECRET into line 36 (tweepy.Stream arguments), but either I did it wrong or that's not the fix.

Answer (score 2):

You're using syntax from an older version of Tweepy.
[Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) changed [`Stream`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.8.0/stream.html) to accept `consumer_key`, `consumer_secret`, `access_token`, and `access_token_secret` parameters for initialization.

Comment: I changed Line 36 to read as follows:
tweet_stream = tweepy.Stream(API_KEY, API_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, TOKEN_SECRET)

This now works, although when I run the script it doesn't do anything after successfully logging in. Is there something wrong with my filtering too?

Comment: By default, `tweepy.Stream` only logs the data. You need to subclass it and override its methods if you want it to do something else. https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.8.0/streaming.html#using-stream